# GNU screen won't send control character from config file but will when set manually

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

My .screenrc has the following line:

```
escape ^Jj
```

However, I can't manage to send a literal ^J in a screen session based on this!

- Version: Screen version 4.06.02 (GNU) 23-Oct-17
- Host: Debian-based Linux

`C-j ?` shows `Command key:  ^J   Literal ^J:  j`

Interestingly, when I set the key using `C-j :escape ^Jj`, I CAN send the control character successfully.

Can anyone explain what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are in a very specific corner case. Ctrl-J is the code for the Enter key (line feed) and so it seems `screen` is treating this specially.

I can type `ls` <kbd>Ret</kbd> and I get a directory listing. But now, sitting at the bare prompt, if I try to type just <kbd>Ret</kbd> nothing happens until I follow up with a <kbd>j</kbd> to send a literal line feed.

My strong recommendation would be to simply not try to use this particular key as the command key for `screen`. (My personal preference is `^L` which doesn't clash much with anything useful; and typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> on the rare occasions when I do need it is perfectly acceptable.)

Comment: I don't see the behaviour you are describing re: the bare `Ret` character.  Also, I have been using C-j as my control character for more than ten years.  This means I will need some convincing to switch (especially as I get my desired behaviour by using `C-j :escape ^Jj`

Comment: Ooh: on my system `C-v <ret>` produces `^M`, which explains the different behaviour from what tripleee describes.

Comment: The concrete Ret key traditionally produces `^M` but on Unix this gets remapped to `^J`. This also depends on your terminal settings.